# Move rows of URLs to proper Root domain heading

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of URLs that I would like properly ordered under their root domain headings.

The row data is currently scrambled with URLs under the wrong domain names as well. [Here’s the example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vFhgKDAUuEklIlTC_HHdFfXqf1g3FgjMkVbVhrN0_nM/edit?usp=sharing).

Is there a formula that can fix all this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. It's not the most elegant as it requires copies of formula in all cells, but it works for all the column with domain names. As it reads domain name, it can't recognize nothing from "other" category

```
=ifna(query(flatten($B$6:$G$7),"select * where Col1 like '%"&lower($A11)&"%' and Col1 like '%"&lower(B$10)&"%'"))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow - thanks so much! This is close enough to an ideal solution [would be great if 'Other' category was filled with any domains not previously captured - but all good] so I'll be marking as the answer. Thanks!